# For loop statement in batch program repeats 5 times

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, pdf-generation

But I'm still having an issue with regards to the program I posted previously. I think there is a problem in my for loop statement because after I opened the file "passwords.csv", I noticed that the loop repeated 5 times.

The first record R_000100.pdf was initially assigned the password 8337, but repeated in other rows and reassigned with other random passwords. And when I tried to open the PDF file, it seems that the last random password assigned (which is 13429) was really its password, and not 8337.

What should I do to correct the program wherein after the all the PDF files have been combined and assigned with passwords, the program will already stop the loop and exit? Thus having only one entry in the output file "passwords.csv" and won't repeat 5 times.

Below is the complete batch program I accomplished, with the help of Peter Wright.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=ABCDEF_." %%i in ('dir *.txt *.pdf /b') do (

TXTtoPDF A_%%i.txt A_%%i.pdf -pps4 -pfs10.9
TXTtoPDF B_%%i.txt B_%%i.pdf -pps4 -pfs8.9
TXTtoPDF C_%%i.txt C_%%i.pdf -pps4 -plm50 -prm50 -pfs7.9
TXTtoPDF D_%%i.txt D_%%i.pdf -pps4 -plm60 -prm60 -pfs8.9
TXTtoPDF E_%%i.txt E_%%i.pdf -pps5 -pot -pfs10
TXTtoPDF F_%%i.txt F_%%i.pdf -pps5 -pot -pfs12

set pass=!random!
pdftk *%%i.pdf cat output PDF\R_%%i.pdf user_pw !pass!
echo %%i R_%%i.pdf !pass! >> passwords.csv

)

echo                ***************************************************
echo                *                                                 *
echo                *       PDF REPORTS SUCCESSFULLY GENERATED.       *
echo                *       PLEASE TYPE EXIT AT COMMAND PROMPT.       *
echo                *                                                 *
echo                ***************************************************
pause
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy, what you have to do is give the batch file the logic to realise which line it is up to.

#### Replace :

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=ABCDEF_." %%i in ('dir *.txt *.pdf /b') do (
```

#### With :

```
set /a count=0
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=ABCDEF_." %%i in ('dir *.txt *.pdf /b') do (
set /a count+=1
if !count! equ 1 (
```

**Note :** add an extra bracket when closing the for-loop for the if-loop

This way, it will count each line the for-loop parse's. If you want to set your password for the second or fifth line, replace `if !count! equ 1 (` with `if !count! equ 2 (` or `if !count! equ 5 (` respectively.

It is useful to do this in all batch files when using for-loops. It is done by default when using an actual programming language.

Hope this helped.

Yours Mona

Comment: I tried using your code, but what happens is that only 1 combined PDF file is created. Example, if I set it to equ 1, only R_000001.pdf is created. If set to equ 5, only R_000005.pdf is created and so on. Yes, it creates only 1 entry in password.csv, but it defeats the purpose of making combined PDFs for each set simultaneously (A_000001.pdf,..F_000001.pdf should have a combined PDF R_000001.pdf and so on). Anyway, this has already been addressed by the revisions done by Mr. Peter Wright in my other post. But thanks for your suggestions. Your inputs in per line parsing was helpful.

Comment: you could use a nested for loop, one to create as many .pdf files as u desired and one to parse line input. To do the prior use `for /l %%a in (1,1, [desired amount of pdf files to create]) do (` However, make sure your variables (%%a and %%i) are not confused. **Note :** im not use to `TXTtoPDF` so I can't really see whats going on, but other then that, your should be able to use `for /l` to fix the problem.